# How can I run a code in background service when a push notification is received on Xamarin Forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub

I'm needing help. I need to execute a job (send to the server the UserId and the user location) **even if the app is closed.** I have tried many different approaches but I couldn't make it work.

It's an Xamarin forms app (android & iOS). I'm focused on Android side.
I have a push notification service working (FCM using  the azure-NotificationHub) if necessary for the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this task executed at a regular cadence, I would recommend adding a `service` to your application that will run in the background and largely be separated from the state of the rest of your application. You can find some documentation on that here: [Run Background Service - Android](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service).

You mentioned that you have a Notification Hub if necessary - essentially the Android Client SDK for Notification Hubs will be creating a service like the one linked above and listening for events to trigger certain actions. If you need data at random (i.e. not at a regular cadence) this could be a good approach. However, assuming you just want an updated location every few minutes, it's probably simpler to just run your own background service.

Comment: I should also mention - the ANH Xamarin SDK wraps the Android SDK mentioned above. So the answer is applicable to either environment.